# TestNG custom error message on timeout

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I would like to know if there's any way of customizing the timeout exception error message.

My test is parametrized by using a DataProvider so i would like to include information about the parameters in the error message in order to know what particular scenario failed.

Error Message

```
Method org.testng.internal.TestNGMethod.testEndpoint() didn't finish within the time-out 8000
```

Stacktrace

```
org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method     
org.testng.internal.TestNGMethod.testEndpoint() didn't finish within the time-out 8000
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1322)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener class by implementing the interface [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html) and in onTestFailure() obtain the exception using [getThrowable()](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestResult.html#getThrowable%28%29)

```
String stackTraceString =      Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(getCurrentTestResult().getThrowable());
```

In the same manner you should be able to setThrowable() with modified error texting (did not check myself).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your dataprovider params from the TestResult object.  As suggested by Vlad, implement the ITestListener interface.

In onTestFailure, get the parameters, using result.getParameters and get the exception using getThrowable.  Create a new Throwable with your custom message, append your params and probably append the existing message (there's a constructor for it) and then set this Throwable to the result object with result.setThrowable.